# Android SharedPreference

Tags: android

имеется код класса SharedPrefManager

```
public class SharedPrefManager {
    private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
    private static Context ctx;

private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "user";

private  static final String KEY_USER_ID = "keyuserid";
private  static final String KEY_USER_LOGIN = "keyuserlogin";
private  static final String KEY_USER_EMAIL = "keyuseremail";
private  static final String KEY_USER_GENDER = "keyusergender";
private  static final String KEY_USER_PHONE = "keyuserphone";    

private SharedPrefManager(Context context){
    ctx = context;
}

public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context){
    if(mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public boolean userLogin(User user){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(KEY_USER_ID,user.getId());
    editor.putString(KEY_USER_LOGIN,user.getLogin());
    editor.putString(KEY_USER_EMAIL,user.getEmail());
    editor.putString(KEY_USER_GENDER,user.getGender());
    editor.putString(KEY_USER_PHONE,user.getPhone());
    editor.apply();
    return true;

}

public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_LOGIN,null)!=null)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public User getUser(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return new User(
                sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_USER_ID,0),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_LOGIN,null),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_EMAIL,null),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_GENDER,null),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_PHONE,null)
        );
    }
```

Как я понял:

1. userLogin - метод, который сохраняет свойства класса в
   SharedPreference
2. isLoggenIn - проверяет, есть ли в
       SharedPreference свойства пользователя. Если есть, то значит   пользователь авторизован.
3. getUser - метод получения свойств    Пользователя.

Все правильно я понял?

Теперь, как они вызываются в Activity?
1)SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(); - это сохранение пользователя.

А как его получить? (getUser). 
Просто в самом классе User, есть такой метод... и я не пойму, как именно достать из SharedPreference. И в примере этот метод вообще не использовался

UPDATE:
Текущий код:
при запуске fragmenta хочу вывести id сохраненного города в textview для проверки, но ничего не появляется

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
       ...
        citySelectedTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.citySelected);
        if(!SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getContext()).isSelectedCity()){
            City city =SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getContext()).getCity();
            citySelectedTV.setText(city.getId());
        }
```

Как сохраняю (класс адаптер для вывода записей в cardview:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

                public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFullCity);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {                  Toast.makeText(ctx,cities.indexOf(getAdapterPosition()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    City city =(City)cities.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    String title = "Был выбран населенный пункт '"+city.getTitle()+"'";
                    Toast.makeText(ctx,title,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(ctx).selectCity(city);
```

Код класса SharedPreference (к выбору города относятся 3 последних метода):

```
public class SharedPrefManager {
    private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
    private static Context ctx;

    private static final String SHARED_PREF_USER = "user";

    private  static final String KEY_USER_ID = "keyuserid";
    private  static final String KEY_USER_LOGIN = "keyuserlogin";
    private  static final String KEY_USER_EMAIL = "keyuseremail";
    private  static final String KEY_USER_GENDER = "keyusergender";
    private  static final String KEY_USER_PHONE = "keyuserphone";

    private static final String SHARED_PREF_CITY = "city";
    private static final String KEY_CITY_ID = "keycityid";
    private static final String KEY_CITY_REGION = "keycityregion";
    private static final String KEY_CITY_AUTONOM = "keycityautonom";
    private static final String KEY_CITY_AREA = "keycityarea";
    private static final String KEY_CITY_CITY = "keycitycity";
    private static final String KEY_CITY_CITY_2 = "keycitycity2";

    private SharedPrefManager(Context context){
        ctx = context;
    }

    public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public boolean userLogin(User user){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_USER,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(KEY_USER_ID,user.getId());
        editor.putString(KEY_USER_LOGIN,user.getLogin());
        editor.putString(KEY_USER_EMAIL,user.getEmail());
        editor.putString(KEY_USER_GENDER,user.getGender());
        editor.putString(KEY_USER_PHONE,user.getPhone());
        editor.apply();
        return true;

    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_USER,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_LOGIN,null)!=null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public User getUser(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_USER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return new User(
                sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_USER_ID,0),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_LOGIN,null),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_EMAIL,null),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_GENDER,null),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_PHONE,null)
        );
    }

    public boolean logout(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_USER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isSelectedCity(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_CITY,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_CITY_ID,0)!=0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public City getCity(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_CITY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return new City(
                sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_CITY_ID,0),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_CITY_REGION,null),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_CITY_AUTONOM,null),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_CITY_AREA,null),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_CITY_CITY,null),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_CITY_CITY_2,null)
        );
    }



    public boolean selectCity(City city){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_CITY,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(KEY_CITY_ID,city.getId());
        editor.putString(KEY_CITY_REGION,city.getRegion());
        editor.putString(KEY_CITY_AUTONOM,city.getAutonom());
        editor.putString(KEY_CITY_AREA,city.getArea());
        editor.putString(KEY_CITY_CITY,city.getCity());
        editor.putString(KEY_CITY_CITY_2,city.getCity_2());
        editor.apply();
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: `SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getUser()`?

Comment: User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getUser()?

Comment: Да, вроде так должно быть

Comment: @ЮрийСПб   Ничего не выводится, обновил код

Comment: Вы не в разных активити, случаем, данные записываете читаете?

Comment: Ну использую я фрагмент. Класс CityAdapter - получаю данные с сервера и записываю в cardview, где на нажатии я хочу сохранить в preference. CityFragment - это класс для работы с фрагментом, где я хочу получить сохраненный город.

Comment: Выглядит код рабочим. Попробуйте префы так получать: `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`

Comment: **!** - лишний, по-моему, в этой проверке `if(!SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getContext()).isSelectedCity())`

Comment: выдало exception E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xf при удалении !

Comment: City city = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getCity() не видит метод getCity()

Comment: Потому что `setText()` принимает `int` за `id` ресурса - нужно конвертнуть в строку `citySelectedTV.setText(String.valueOf(city.getId()));`

Comment: спасибо, заработало